# How to display cookies on all pages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to add cookies using c#, everything works good for me. But I need to make it visible on all pages. So please let me know where I need to add: `;path=/` in my code. here is my code:

```html
<script>
  function banner() {
    $("#bannercookies").removeClass("open");
  }
  $(document).ready(function () {
    if ($.cookie("popup_1_2") == null) {
      $("#bannercookies").addClass("open");
      $.cookie("popup_1_2", "2");
    }
  });
</script>

<div id="bannercookies" class="banner-cookies">
  This website uses cookies to ensure you get the best experience on our
  website.
  <a href="PrivacyPolicy.html#section11" class="link-underlined white"
    >Cookies Policy</a
  >
  <button class="gotitbtn" onclick="banner();">GOT IT</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is your question? Could you explain a bit more, what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set/unset a cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-do-i-set-unset-a-cookie-with-jquery)

Comment: What do you mean by "visible"? How is this related to C#?

Comment: I want to make the cookies available on all internal pages.

Comment: currently cookies appears only on front page, but not internal pages, so how can I make it work on multiple pages?

Comment: What does that mean? Usually and pretty simplified, cookies are set per domain and then accessible on all pages of that domain

Comment: What is the difference between "front page" and "internal page"?

Answer (score 0):

`$.cookie("popup_1_2", "2", { path: "/" })` should do what you want

> ```
> $.cookie("test", 1, {
>    expires : 10,           // Expires in 10 days
>
>    path    : '/',          // The value of the path attribute of the cookie
>                            // (Default: path of page that created the cookie).
>
>    domain  : 'jquery.com', // The value of the domain attribute of the cookie
>                            // (Default: domain of page that created the cookie).
>
>    secure  : true          // If set to true the secure attribute of the cookie
>                            // will be set and the cookie transmission will
>                            // require a secure protocol (defaults to false).
> });
> ```

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1458728/4536543